# Apache htaccesses redirect URL having plus(+)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using apache redirect rules to redirect URLs to my application.

My  RewriteRule is like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/search-(.*?)-page /myapplication/search.html?query=$1   [L,PT,B]
```

When i make a query/request `/search-c++-page` or `/search-c%2B%2B-page` , on my application side for `request.getParameter("query")` i get **c-**  instead of **c++**.

Why is it happening ? Is there any configuration change required to make it working ?

Comment: Yes it is in httpd.conf. I have tested for all other patterns and it is working, except c++

Comment: Yes, as per the RewriteRule , it is suppose to work. I am struggling to fix only for inputs with ++.

Comment: I am using apache 2.2 , which version of apache are you using ?

Comment: Try this rule: `RewriteRule ^/?search-([^-]+)-page/?$ myapplication/search.html?query=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: No its not helping .

Comment: That means you have some other code/config issue not this rewrite rule.

Comment: @anubhava Is there any global rule we can define to make ++ to - ? Is there any way to figure out any rule is enabled or disabled ?

Comment: Enable .htaccess and test my suggested rule there.